# AWStats and Time Taken to serve the Request

Tags: iis-6, log-files, awstats

I have several IIS 6 web servers I manage and I turn on the time-taken field in the logs. I use AWStats to generate various reports from the log data. One of my developer counterparts has recently asked me to provide a report based on the Time-Taken data. She is specifically looking for top 20 pages sorted by average time-taken, plus min and max time-takens.

I am thinking that I can achieve this by creating an ExtraSection in my AWStats config file. Is this feasible? Does anyone have any config samples they are willing to share? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to include for the total time taken to serve the entire page and contents to the client (i.e. for the client to download all the stylesheets, javascript, images, flash, etc), or just the time taken for the initial page to be generated and sent?

Comment: I am looking for the entire page's contents (CSS, JS, images, etc), but in case that's too complicated, then the initial page alone will be enough for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be very difficult to know how long the entire page takes to load. Not impossible, but difficult. You will need 'group' by referrals.

For each PHP/ASP/Whatever/HTML page that is output, then find all the requests immediately after it that have the referrer of the just-requested page, for that IP address. Keep going until that IP requests another HTML page. Repeat and rinse.

As for how to actually do this in AWStats, I honestly don't know. You might need to do up a script or something to parse the logs manually.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hack that will probably do what you want: http://www.pgs-soft.com/installing-awstats-on-iis-7-0-time-taken-extra-section.html

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the question that you're trying to answer.  Is is:

"Our servers are overloaded, find the offending pages,"

in which case you'd be doing something with the IIS logging.  On the other hand, you may be trying to answer:

"Which pages are the slowest to load from a user perspetive,"

in which case AWStats isn't going to help you, you'd have to use an analysis tool, probably running outside your network.